# Record GLSurfaceView on < Android 4.3

Tags: android, opengl-es, camera, glsurfaceview

I'm developing an app for applying effects to the camera image in real-time. Currently I'm using the `MediaMuxer` class in combination with `MediaCodec`. Those classes were implemented with Android 4.3.
Now I wanted to redesign my app and make it compatible for more devices. The only thing I found in the internet was a combination of FFmpeg and OpenCV, but I read that the framerate is not very well if I want to use a high resolution. Is there any possibility to encode video in real-time while capturing the camera image without using `MediaMuxer` and `MediaCodec`?

PS: I'm using GLSurfaceView for OpenGL fragment shader effects. So this is a must-have.

Answer (score 0):

Real-time encoding of large frames at a moderate frame rate is not going to happen with software codecs.

`MediaCodec` was introduced in 4.1, so you can still take advantage of hardware-accelerated compression so long as you can deal with the [various problems](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#q9).  You'd still need an alternative to `MediaMuxer` if you want a .mp4 file at the end.

Some commercial game recorders, such as [Kamcord](https://github.com/kamcord/kamcord-android-sdk/wiki/Supported-Devices-Android-Versions) and [Everyplay](https://github.com/Everyplay/everyplay-android-sdk), claim to work on Android 4.1+.  So it's technically possible, though I don't know if they used non-public APIs to feed surfaces directly into the video encoder.

In pre-Jellybean Android it only gets harder.

(For anyone interested in recording GL in >= 4.3, see [EncodeAndMuxTest](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#EncodeAndMuxTest) or [Grafika's](https://github.com/google/grafika) "Record GL app".)

Comment: The ">= 4.3" example was for other people who find the question by searching.  For you, the solution -- and whether or not there is one -- depends on what API level you're targeting, whether or not you want to use the NDK, and how willing you are to use non-public APIs.  There is an existence proof that the problem can be solved on API 4.1 for some (perhaps not all) devices.  You will probably need to use `SurfaceMediaSource.cpp` / `GraphicBufferSource.cpp` as your starting point.

Comment: I want to support at least Android 4.0