# How to get the image stream when I use GLsurfaceview renderer

Tags: android, glsurfaceview

I want to get the image stream when I render in glsurfaceview with finger
The purpose is record the render form glsurfaceview , I was done it with camera use surfacetexture to encode the .mp4, but I can't get the render from glsurfaceview when I draw.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22461402/295004, note the links at the bottom of answer.

Comment: Hi @Morrison Chang Thanks for Related link, same problem that I want to record the screen, and same cause I want to encode the GLsurfaceview content avoid the upper vision, i'm want do in 4.4, even that I know have useful MediaProjection API in 5.0, Thanks your advice again, help my question more specific

Answer (score 0):

- Get your `GLSurfaceView`'s `EGLContext` with `EGL14.eglGetCurrentContext()`
- Use the `EGLContext` above as shared context in a separated thread to create another `EGLContext` for recording
- The recording `EGLContext` will render into a `Surface` get from `MediaCodec.createInputSurface`, also it use the same texture from `GLSurfaceView`
- Use `MediaMuxer` to mux your `MediaCodec` output to mp4
- Then you can record your `GLSurfaceView` to mp4

See the example in [sample code](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/CameraCaptureActivity.java)

Comment: Hi @Alijandro Thanks your advice, I will try this way, it look can work, I search the Opengl ES2.0 theory in Android recently, I think the EGL interface can help me to solve the problem, Thanks again.

Comment: I use the other way to record the glsurface by binding the Multiple texture not your way, but thanks again

Comment: @CapybaraChan congratulations! Could you share some information of your solution? If you don't mind, other people get here will find more valuable information. We encourage people share their knowledge here, if you don't mind, you can post your solution as an answer and flag it as the best answer.

Comment: @CapybaraChan I am looking into this as well, if you don't mind sharing the solution. Thanks.